# Printing postscript with lp -o raw gives different result

Tags: postscript, cups

I have postscript file, generated with a 'print-to-file' trick.
The file is generated from a one-page pdf.

When I try to print this file and want two copies of it, I use the following command:

```
lp -o raw -n 2 27116_6-pack_Pixel_inlay-duplo.ps
```

On one computer (iMac with cups 2.2.0) it will print two single sided prints, which is the expected behaviour.

On three other iMac's the same command (and exactly the same file), will generate a double sided print. I checked the Cups version on one of these iMac's, it was 2.1.0
So I upgraded this machine from El Capitain to MacOs Sierra and got Cups 2.2.5 hoping there was an issue in the Cups 2.1.0 version.

Still I got the same problem of a double sided print, when expecting 2 single pages.

I checked the Fierry Workstation, the top entry is the one with the correct behaviour. The second entry got the original pdf tile as task name.
[image]

Any suggestion how this is possible?

By the way, I was suprised that the `-n` option worked when sending a a postscript file with the `-o raw` option. I thought nothing will be changed/added to the file when sending it raw.

Comment: Most likely you have Duplex set to true in the CUPS configuration somewhere. I can't (obviously) tell without seeing the file. I notice from your screenshot that the two files are **considerably** different in size, one is nearly twice the size of the other which suggests to me that one of the files has /Copies 2 and the other has two complete copies of the PostScript program. These will behave differently on a printer with /Duplex; the first case will produce two sheets (one page,  twice), the second case will produce duplexed output (two pages, duplex is true). I'd still say CUPS config.

Comment: @KenS It is the exact same file, (on disk 40 MB). When I do `-n 3` Fiery Workstation will say 120 MB.

Comment: The `-n 2` works with `-o raw` because CUPS *WILL* leave the original PostScript file unchanged, but simply sends it to the print queue twice...

Answer (score 0):

On further inspection, I found out the problem.

When going to http://localhost:631/admin/ and looking into the configuration of the iMac's, I see the following long connection string, which is different on the the iMac with a short connection string.

on the iMac that is giving wrong behaviour
[image: wrong setup]

on the iMac that is working
[image: correct setup]

I modified the connection setting to `Canon-IPC650`

And after this change on every computer, all is working fine now.

I assume the long connection string with all the `%20 %28` is escaped wrong or something like that.

Comment: I'd rather guess the printer definitions or the printer defaults were different.

Comment: Printing a postscript file gives me the guarantee the printjob is always the same. The defaults where used when the postscript file was generated.

Comment: Still drivers may change the device's settings like adjusting the page position *before* the actual job starts. Drivers could even redefine operators.